# Nova action with custom message for confirmation - tool required?

Tags: laravel, laravel-nova

In the Nova docs, it is indicated that fields can be used to require input from a user before dispatching an action.

https://nova.laravel.com/docs/3.0/actions/defining-actions.html#action-fields

```
public function fields()
{
    return [
        Text::make('Subject'),
    ];
}
```

These fields are referenced in `handle`:

```
public function handle(ActionFields $fields, Collection $models)
{
    foreach ($models as $model) {
        (new AccountData($model))->send($fields->subject);
    }
}
```

It is unclear from the docs what `AccountData` should be.  When I instantiate a model, it tells me `send` is undefined.  What is the simplest way to get a modal to popup that includes the defined fields?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you should do is to create a new action with artisan nova:action  and in that actions fields method define the fields user should fill out. They work in the same way as normal fields in a resource.
Then inside the actions method inside the resource where you want the action, you add it to the return array in actions method.

eg:
inside resource:

```
   public    function actions(Request $request)
   {
        return [
            QuickImportAction::make($this->resource, $request)->standalone()
    ];
    )
```

And then inside the Nova/Actions/ after action is generated:

```
 public function handle(ActionFields $fields, Collection $models)
    {
        if($models->count()>0) return Action::danger("Replace in filters is not ready, unselect and replace in all");
    }

    /**
     * Get the fields available on the action.
     *
     * @return array
     */
    public function fields()
    {
        $replace = "";

        return [
            Heading::make("<div class=' text-secondary'> NOTE! only selected filters rows will be replaced</div>")
                   ->textAlign('center')->asHtml(),
];
)
```

EDIT:
Sorry, let me reply to your actual question. The

```
(new <class>)->method
```

Is the same as:

```
$model = new MyModel();
$model->method()
```

So its different from application to application.